# Hardhat tests - deploy with arguments [typescript]

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, typescript, waffle

I am writing tests for my contract in typescript. I am deploying the contracts like this:

```
import { Contract } from "../typechain-types/index";
import ContractArtifact from "../artifacts/contracts/Contract.sol/Contract.json";
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { ethers, waffle } from "hardhat";


let contractOwner: SignerWithAddress;
let deployedContract: Contract;

const { deployContract } = waffle;
[contractOwner] = await ethers.getSigners();
deployedContract = (await deployContract(
        contractOwner,
        ContractArtifact
      )) as Contract;
```

Is it possible to set constructor arguments when deploying with typescript? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet I see you are using waffle's function `deployContract`, it receives 3 arguments:

- wallet to send the deploy transaction
- contract information (abi and bytecode)
- contract constructor arguments

Just include the array of arguments at the end:

```
deployedContract = (await deployContract(
        contractOwner,
        ContractArtifact,
        [argument1, argument2,...,last argument]
      )) as Contract;
```